# What are the adversities on sending HTML from the DB?

Tags: sql, security

this is the way I am receiving an object from the DB

```
{ 
  BET: 57630343,
  CUSTOMER: 181645,
  SPORT: 'MLB',
  'XX_FILL OPEN': '<button class="btn btn-xs" ng-click="fillOpen(57630343)">Fill Open</button>',
  XX_VIEW: '<select>\r\n  <option value="volvo" label="Volvo">Volvo</option>\r\n  <option value="saab" label="Saab">Saab</option>\r\n  <option value="mercedes" label="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>\r\n  <option value="audi" label="Audi">Audi</option>\r\n</select>',
  XX_CANCEL: '<input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="soccer"  onchange="fillOpen(57630343)"/>' 
}
```

as you can see the props starting with index of `XX` are HTML elements. I am taking those elements in the front-end with JavaScript and injecting them into the DOM.

This is the first time I am doing this. I am used to take an XML and send it to the front-end as a JSON so I render it.

Is there something wrong with the way we are doing it now? is there any unsafe technique here? would be easier for hackers to break into my system?

Comment: I don't think there's anything technically wrong as long as you json_encode properly your strings. But there's something conceptually wrong however: you break the data/presentation layers paradigm - if you cared about it. If you're concerned about security, then you should firstly check your javascript methods themselves. Nothing done on the client should be trusted anyway. If you have an issue, it is upstream of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ditto on Sebas comment which should really be the answer. Security should always be handled on the server side which means this practice shouldn't make things worse.

Additionally, storing html like this is going to be a nightmare to maintain. For instance,  if for some reason the 'BET' id needs to change, you will need to regenerate all of the html for that row. See [data normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) for more information on why this can cause issues.